# Allow blocked content inside Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, security, internet-explorer

I'm using some HTML help files in Visual Studio 2010 that include scripts for searching.

The first time I open the help files inside a new Visual Studio 2010 session, I get an information bar:

> To help protect your security, your browser has restricted this file from showing active content that could access your computer. Click here for options...

I would like to get around having to click "Allow Blocked Content" on the information bar every time.

I know that I can turn off all security measures in Tools/Options/Web Browser/Internet Explorer Options, but I would like to find the specific options to allow the help pages to display without turning security off completely.

Is there a way to find out exactly what triggered the content blocking?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this is being caused by the [Mark of the Web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628.aspx). This should disappear when on running on an actual web server, so in order to to stop having the message pop up, you can add your own `MOTW` to simulate that it has been downloaded from the web. You can try adding either:

```
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
```

or

```
<!-- saved from url=(0016)http://localhost -->
```

to the top of your HTML pages depending on what security zone you want to use.